# counting the number of items in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string as shown bellow:

```
SIM types:Azadi|Validity:2 Nights|Expirable:yes
```

I have the following code to seperate them by `|` and then show them line by line

```
$other = "SIM types:Azadi|Validity:2 Nights|Expirable:yes";

$others['items'][] = explode("|",$other);
for($i = 0; $i < count($others['items']); $i++){
    echo $others['items'][$i];
}
```

but the `for` loop is iterated only once and prints only the first value. This is what i am getting now:

SIM types:Azadi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
$others['items'] = explode("|",$other);
$my_count = count($others['items']);
for($i = 0; $i < $my_count; $i++){
    echo $others['items'][$i];
}
```

Comment: This part, count($others['items']) is not efficent. Better is to use function outside loop like, $total = count($others['items']); and change the loop like, for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){...}

Comment: Yah thanku @web2students.com I have changed it,thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Change

`$others['items'][] = explode("|",$other);`

to

`$others['items'] = explode("|",$other);`

remove `[]`

Explode will return a array. ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$other = "SIM types:Azadi|Validity:2 Nights|Expirable:yes";

$others['items'] = explode("|",$other);
for($i = 0; $i < count($others['items']); $i++){
    echo $others['items'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$other = "SIM types:Azadi|Validity:2 Nights|Expirable:yes";

$others = explode("|",$other);
$total = count($others);

for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
    echo $others[$i];
}
?>
```